# Father-to-son component tree with guest component

Tags: angular

In Angular 2 I have a hierarchy of components. Within the tree, however, I need to show yet another element which is decoupled from the object hierarchy. It will be a spinner component. Somehow it does not want to show up.

```
<parent>
    <child>
        <grandchild>
            <spinner></spinner>
        </grandchild>
    <child>
</parent>
```

- `parent` includes `child` in the template,
- `child` includes `grandchild` in the template.
- `grandchild` does not include `spinner` in the template, but wants to show it (it uses `ng-content` for that). Or perhaps, at some point the `child` would want to show the spinner instead.

How do I get it to work? Does a parent always have to specify possible children? PLease let me know what I'm doing wrong.

[The example plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/GYvUuLmo0hBypXuELMhK?p=preview)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you add `<ng-content></ng-content>` to the template of a component, then child elements are displayed instead of `<ng-content></ng-content>`.

This way you can pass child components to parents.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'child'
  template: `<grand-child><ng-content></ng-content></grand-child>`
})
```

```
@Component({
  selector: 'grand-child'
  template: `some content before <ng-content></ng-content>some content after`
})
```

Then you can use it like

```
<child><my-spinner></my-spinnger></child>
```

Comment: Thanks, but this is exactly how I thought it would work - in the plunker you'll see `ng-content` in the Grandchild template. (I edited my post to be more precise.) Or is there any nuance I am overlooking?

Comment: Sorry, didn't see the Plunker. https://plnkr.co/edit/J1qHqdjRn7NYgTyqIxLv?p=preview. Your Plunker didn't contain any `<ng-content>`. Perhaps not pressed save?

Comment: Sorry, my fault, indeed the plunker had not been saved and did not contain granchild. Now it should be up-to-date

Comment: The whole chain needs `<ng-content>` (the spinner doesn't if it doesn't get children passed) https://plnkr.co/edit/GpwMh0BLbq3GhJxVXDiE?p=preview

Comment: Yes, indeed, yet without <the-child> and <the-grandchild> element then. Perfect, thanks.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer - How would I use ContentChild here?  I have posted a separate question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42775452/how-can-i-use-contentchild-children-in-grandchild